# Update Object in for in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I'm trying to update an object with child properties within my angular application.

object 1:

```
$scope.osbStep = {
                 test0Nav : {
                     current : false,
                    complete : false,
                    hidden : false
                 },test1Nav : {
                        current : false,
                        complete : false,
                        hidden : false
                 },test2Nav : {
                        current : false,
                        complete : false,
                        hidden : false
                     },
             };
```

$broadcast object 2:

```
var currentPage = { test0Nav : { current : true }};
$rootScope.$broadcast('step:set', currentPage);
```

How can I update object 1 with object 2 ?

I am looping through and matching Properties. BuT I need to update object 1 with object 2 data. My logs are only returning strings.

```
$scope.$on('step:set', function( event, currentStepData ){

                    for ( var key in currentStepData ) {
                        if( currentStepData.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                            var currentKey = key;
                            for ( var foo in $scope.osbStep ) {
                                if( $scope.osbStep.hasOwnProperty( foo ) ) {

                                    if (currentKey === foo){

                                        console.log( 'foo ', foo );
                                        console.log( 'currentKey 'currentKey );

                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: so are you getting the right values inside your loop?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/

In your case, I think angular.merge is the most appropriate:

```
angular.merge($scope.osbStep, currentPage);
```

PS: If you prefer, I think you could use jQuery extend method too (should be a bit faster for big objects)